# object has no attribute 'lower' for sentiment analysis

Tags: python-requests, attributeerror, sentiment-analysis, lowercase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RLkD.png)
for sentiments analysis the data processing part show error that

## It show : 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

The error message "'float' object has no attribute 'lower'" typically occurs when I try to use the lower() method on a float object. The lower() method is used to convert a string to lowercase,
How can I solve this problem. Though the same code is working for other data but it happens for this data. I don't how can i solve this.

Comment: Please do not show code in an image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors